# Drupal Exposed filter with auto-submit works only once

Tags: 7, ajax, views

I have a View with an exposed filter that uses Ajax and auto-submit. Now, the problem I have is that it works only once.

For example, there is a check-box and when I tick it, the Ajax comes to action and the filtering is done. But when I try to use any other filter, or the same check box nothing happens. Do you guys have any idea?

Note that I've made some modifications to the view template and the views-exposed-form template.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be useful to describe which kind of modifications you made to the templates, in order to delimit a bit further the issue. Do you see the same problem without the modifications?

Comment: No, without the modifications it works well. Also, I think the issue is related to this part: <div class="<?php print $classes; ?>">. I have two of this divs in the view template, and I am pretty sure this is causing the problem. Unfortunately I couldn't find any good tutorials on how Ajax is searching the DOM

Comment: Eventually I made it work by replacing the print $classes with the same content of $classes except the view-dom-id-123125412312. e.g. class="view view-companies view-id-companies view-display-id-page"